# Wired connection vs wireless bandwidth battle

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, gaming, appletv

I have a wired connection to my PC using a netger d6200 router. We have apple TV in our house which is connected via wireless (obviously). People like to stream netflix via apple tv which is fine, except as I am wired, is there anyway to make it so I dont' constantly spike in latency while they are streaming. It feels wierd that my game probably needs like 25kbps to stay at a reasonable ping yet i'm constantly shifting between 50ms and 250ms every few seconds.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Thats an ADSL2+ router, max bandwidth you have is 24/1Mb, likely a lot less. This doesnt really have anything to do with wireless vs wired, its the fact that your demand for bandwith is more than you have available.

A simple fix is to ask the others to set the quality 1-2 steps down on the apple TV, so if they're watching in 1080p try 720p or 640x480. This should hopefully free up some bandwidth and stop the modem from having to queue packets. Or subscribe to a faster service.

If thats not enough of you need better then a router with strong QoS rules is needed, but you won't often find that on consumer grade equipment so you'll be paying more. Hardware recommendations are out of scope here.

Comment: i set netflix to stream at SD which is 0.7gb per hour, i calculated that to be 700 megs an hour, per minute thats about 11 or 12 megs, which means it should be downloading at 200kbps, my speed isn't great i usually get around 6-8mpbs down on adsl2 how reliable is netflix streaming profile, i find it hard to believe that I should be spiking on games if only 1/3 of my total download speed is being used at once

Comment: Its possible @Sim that your upload is the root problem, at an 8Mb line profile most telcos will provision 512kbps up, so thats about 50KBps after ATM overhead. Pretty easy to consume. Netflix doesnt stream at a completely consistent rate as it will buffer in "bursts" sometimes. This could cause the spikes you see. You could use wireshark to see the real rates but realistically that line is rapidly becoming viable for only a single light user. If you can get VDSL or Cable you should.